# Extending sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

On extending my default sharepoint site (port 80) as Intranet site, it shows me this message

The trust relationship between the primary domain and the trusted domain failed.

Let me know what could be the reason behind

Comment: Google is your friend...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try google? I think [this](http://forums.iis.net/t/1184938.aspx/1) may be the problem in you scenario, kindly post detail error log